Cannot get attribute after pyinstaller pack when using Multiprocesssing
It's so strange that after using pyinstaller to pack my python file, it cannot find the method, even after i already put everything inside the ui.py.
What makes things more strange is that for some methods like process_author_data from other modules like
author_extractor.py, it can run normally.
Here is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, Listbox, Button, Entry, Label
import threading
import os

from author_extractor import process_author_data

import csv
import multiprocessing
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Semaphore

selenium_version = int(webdriver.__version__.split('.')[0])

multiprocessing.freeze_support()
driver_path = 'lib/chromedriver'


class HIndexCache:
    def __init__(self, manager, save_trigger_count=10, filepath='data/h_indices_temp.csv'):
        self.h_indices = manager.dict()
        self.save_trigger_count = save_trigger_count
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.count = manager.Value('i', 0)  # Initialize the count as a managed integer
        self.lock = manager.Lock()  # Use a manager lock to protect access to the count
        # check if file exists, if exists, load the h_indices
        try:
            with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in reader:
                    self.h_indices[row[0]] = row[1]
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def add_h_index(self, author_id, h_index):
        with self.lock:  # Use the manager's lock to synchronize access
            self.h_indices[str(author_id)] = h_index
            self.count.value += 1
            if self.count.value >= self.save_trigger_count:
                self.save_h_indices()
                self.count.value = 0  # Reset count after saving

    def save_h_indices(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            for author_id, h_index in dict(self.h_indices).items():
                writer.writerow([author_id, h_index])
        print("H-indices saved to disk.")

    def get_h_index(self, author_id):
        h_index = self.h_indices.get(str(author_id), None)
        if (h_index is None) or (h_index == ''):
            return None
        else:
            return h_index


class WebDriverManager:
    def __init__(self, semaphore):
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def get_driver(self):
        self.semaphore.acquire()
        if selenium_version < 4:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        return driver

    def return_driver(self, driver):
        driver.quit()
        self.semaphore.release()


def login(user_name, password, driver):
    driver.get('https://www.scopus.com')
    # cookie_banner_close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ontrust-banner-accept"))
    # )
    # cookie_banner_close_button.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signin_link_move"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bdd-email"]').send_keys(user_name)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bdd-elsPrimaryBtn"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bdd-password"]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bdd-elsPrimaryBtn"]').click()


def get_author_info(args):
    # author_id, driver_manager = args
    author_id, driver_manager, h_index_cache, wait_mu, wait_sigma = args
    existing_h_index = h_index_cache.get_h_index(author_id)
    if existing_h_index is not None:
        return existing_h_index
    driver = driver_manager.get_driver()  # 从管理器获取 WebDriver 实例
    try:
        driver.get(f'http://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.url?authorId={author_id}')
        sleep_time = (np.random.rand() - 0.5) * wait_sigma + wait_mu
        sleep(sleep_time)
        # 获取 h-index 的逻辑
        if selenium_version < 4:
            h_index_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="unclickable-count"]')
            institution = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="unclickable-count"]')
            cite_num, pub_num, h_index = [h_index_element[i].text for i in range(3)]
        else:
            h_index_element = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@data-testid="unclickable-count"]')
            institution = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, value='//*[@data-testid="unclickable-count"]')
            cite_num, pub_num, h_index = [h_index_element[i].text for i in range(3)]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e} \n for author {author_id}")
        h_index = None
    finally:
        driver_manager.return_driver(driver)  # 返回 WebDriver 实例到管理器
    if h_index is not None:
        h_index_cache.add_h_index(author_id, h_index)  # Add h-index to cache
    return h_index


def query_h(input_path, output_path, cols_output=None, max_window_num=4, wait_mu=5, wait_sigma=2):
    print('Reading input file...')
    df = pd.read_csv(input_path)
    with Manager() as manager:
        print('Opening process pool...')
        semaphore = manager.Semaphore(max_window_num)
        driver_manager = WebDriverManager(semaphore)
        h_index_cache = HIndexCache(manager)  # Initialize HIndexCache with Manager
        args = [(author_id, driver_manager, h_index_cache, wait_mu, wait_sigma) for author_id in df['Author ID']]
        with Pool(max_window_num) as pool:
            print('Starting...')
            results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(get_author_info, args), total=len(args)))
        df['H-Index'] = results
        h_index_cache.save_h_indices()  # Ensure all remaining data is saved
        if cols_output is not None:
            df[cols_output].to_csv(output_path, index=False)
        print('Writing output file...')
        df.to_csv(output_path, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')


class AuthorApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Author Data Processor")
        self.geometry("900x600")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.data = None
        self.max_window_num = 4  # Default number of windows
        self.wait_mu = 5         # Default average wait time
        self.wait_sigma = 2      # Default standard deviation of wait time

    def create_widgets(self):
        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)

        middle_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        middle_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=10)

        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        # 操作按钮
        self.load_button = Button(top_frame, text="Load Data", command=self.load_data)
        self.load_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        self.extract_button = Button(top_frame, text="Extract Author Info", command=self.run_process_data,
                                     state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.extract_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        self.query_button = Button(top_frame, text="Query H-index", command=self.run_query_h_index, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.query_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        # New settings button
        self.settings_button = Button(top_frame, text="Query H-index Settings", command=self.open_settings,
                                      state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.settings_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        Label(middle_frame, text="Input File Path:").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.input_entry = Entry(middle_frame, width=30)
        self.input_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        Label(middle_frame, text="Output File Path:").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.output_entry = Entry(middle_frame, width=30)
        self.output_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)

        # 新增选择输出目录的按钮
        self.choose_output_button = Button(middle_frame, text="Browse...", command=self.choose_output)
        self.choose_output_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5)


        self.source_list = Listbox(bottom_frame, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
        self.source_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        button_frame = tk.Frame(bottom_frame)
        button_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, padx=10)

        self.add_button = Button(button_frame, text="->", command=self.add_items)
        self.add_button.pack(pady=5)

        self.remove_button = Button(button_frame, text="<-", command=self.remove_items)
        self.remove_button.pack(pady=5)

        # 目标列表框，应该是最后一个被添加
        self.target_list = Listbox(bottom_frame, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
        self.target_list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def load_data(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if file_path:
            self.input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.input_entry.insert(0, file_path)
            usage = 0
            try:
                self.data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                cols = self.data.columns.tolist()
                if ('Author full names' in cols) and ('Correspondence Address' in cols):
                    self.extract_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                    cols = cols + [i for i in ['Full Name*', 'Author Link*', 'Email*', 'Address*', 'Address Country*',
                                   'First Name*', 'Last Name*', 'Author ID*'] if i.strip('*') not in self.data]
                    cols.sort()
                    usage += 1
                else:
                    self.extract_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

                if 'Author ID' in self.data.columns:
                    self.query_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                    self.settings_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                    if 'H-Index' not in self.data.columns:
                        cols.append('H-Index*')
                    cols.sort()
                    usage += 1
                else:
                    self.query_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                    self.settings_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.source_list.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.target_list.delete(0, tk.END)

                if usage <= 0:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Missing required columns: 'Author full names' or"
                                                  " 'Last Name' or 'Correspondence Address' or "
                                                  "'Author ID'. Please try again.")
                else:
                    for col in cols:
                        self.source_list.insert(tk.END, col)
                    # 默认导出条目
                    default_items = [i for i in ['Author Link', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name', 'Email',
                                                 'Address Country', 'H-Index', 'Author ID', 'Author Link*',
                                                 'First Name*', 'Last Name*', 'Full Name*', 'Email*',
                                                 'Address Country*', 'H-Index*', 'Author ID*', ] if i in cols]
                    for item in default_items:
                        self.target_list.insert(tk.END, item)
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to load file: {e}")
                self.extract_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.query_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.settings_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def choose_output(self):
        directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if directory:
            self.output_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.output_entry.insert(0, os.path.join(directory, 'output.csv'))

    def add_items(self):
        selected_items = [self.source_list.get(i) for i in self.source_list.curselection()]
        for item in selected_items:
            if item not in self.target_list.get(0, tk.END):
                self.target_list.insert(tk.END, item)

    def remove_items(self):
        selected_items = list(self.target_list.curselection())
        selected_items.reverse()  # Reverse to delete from end to start to avoid shifting indices
        for i in selected_items:
            self.target_list.delete(i)

    def run_process_data(self):
        input_file_path = self.input_entry.get()
        output_file_path = self.output_entry.get()
        columns_to_save = list(self.target_list.get(0, tk.END))
        if 'H-Index*' in columns_to_save:
            columns_to_save.remove('H-Index')
            messagebox.showwarning('Warning',
                                   'Please use Author ID to query H-Index instead of extracting.')
        columns_to_save = [i.strip('*') for i in columns_to_save]

        threading.Thread(target=self.process_data, args=(input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save)).start()

    def process_data(self, input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save):
        try:
            output = process_author_data(input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Data processed and saved to: \n {output}")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to process data: {e}")

    def run_query_h_index(self):
        self.query_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.settings_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        input_file_path = self.input_entry.get()
        output_file_path = self.output_entry.get()
        columns_to_save = list(self.target_list.get(0, tk.END))
        columns_to_save = [i.strip('*') for i in columns_to_save]
        print('Start querying H')
        threading.Thread(target=self.query_h_index, args=(input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save)).start()

    def query_h_index(self, input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save):
        print('entering querying H')
        self.query_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.settings_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        try:
            query_h(input_file_path, output_file_path, columns_to_save, max_window_num=self.max_window_num,
                    wait_mu=self.wait_mu, wait_sigma=self.wait_sigma)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "H-Index query completed and data is saved.")
            self.query_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.settings_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to query H-Index: {e}")

    def open_settings(self):
        settings_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        settings_window.title("Query H-index Settings")
        settings_window.geometry("300x200")

        tk.Label(settings_window, text="Max Window Number:").pack()
        self.max_window_entry = tk.Entry(settings_window)
        self.max_window_entry.pack()
        self.max_window_entry.insert(0, str(self.max_window_num))

        tk.Label(settings_window, text="Average Wait Time (mu):").pack()
        self.wait_mu_entry = tk.Entry(settings_window)
        self.wait_mu_entry.pack()
        self.wait_mu_entry.insert(0, str(self.wait_mu))

        tk.Label(settings_window, text="Wait Time Std Dev (sigma):").pack()
        self.wait_sigma_entry = tk.Entry(settings_window)
        self.wait_sigma_entry.pack()
        self.wait_sigma_entry.insert(0, str(self.wait_sigma))

        save_button = tk.Button(settings_window, text="Save Settings", command=self.save_settings)
        save_button.pack()

    def save_settings(self):
        try:
            self.max_window_num = int(self.max_window_entry.get())
            self.wait_mu = float(self.wait_mu_entry.get())
            self.wait_sigma = float(self.wait_sigma_entry.get())
            messagebox.showinfo("Settings Updated", "Query H-index settings have been updated successfully.")
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter valid numeric values.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    app = AuthorApp()
    app.mainloop()

This code can run smoothly before packing with Pyinstaller, but after packing it will always show me the error code below:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'get_author_info' on <module '__main__' from '/var/folders/6x/bvp37ls15nlgh52zvhlw_gp80000gn/T/_MEItdxenr/ui.py'>

